# phpmyadmin SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin, virtualmin

Hi I keep getting this error when opening `phpmyadmin` on the server side. Would anyone please give me step by step guidance on how to solve the problem?

[phpMyAdmin - Error
Error during session start; please check your PHP or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

`session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)][1]`

Comment: What does the error log say then? Have you ensured that phpmyadmin can write to the session directory? Are cookies enabled in the browser?

Comment: What is your PHP version could it be 7.1.x ? IF so could you please update your phpmyadmin version? Seems like PHP can't access to session file location.

Comment: How can I access the session directory to ensure if phpadmin can write? @OptimusCrime

Comment: Log into the server using SSH.

Comment: thanks problem solved now i have a new one